# How do I strip() and split() using variables?

Tags: python-3.x, variables, split, null, strip

```
W_A11, 2008-02, Moving average, 59.66666667, 50.92582302, 68.40751031, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,
W_A11, 2010-03, Moving average, 60, 51.23477459, 68.76522541, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal,
W_A11, 2017-04, Moving average, 59, 50.30812505, 67.69187495, Injuries, Number, Assault, Validated, Whole pop, All ages, Fatal

qdate = int(input("please enter 2000, 2010, or 2017"))
infile = open('injury_statistics.txt', "r")
outfilename = input("please enter the name of the file to which you want to 
                     append ex) injury_statistics_datafile.txt ")
outfile = open(outfilename, "a")
stripped_character = input("please enter any character you want stripped 
                            from the data ")
delimiter = input("please enter the delimiter for the file ")
# print(type(stripped_character))
# print(type(delimiter))
# the above two lines prove that stripped_character and delimiter are 
# strings
next(infile)
for line in infile:
    linefromfile = line.strip(stripped_character).split(delimiter)
    tuple1 = tuple(linefromfile)
    if int(tuple1[1][:4]) == qdate:
        outfile.write('\n')
        outfile.write(str(linefromfile))
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Strip and split both take strings ex) split('\t'), but for some reason the strings stored by my variables "stripped_character" and "delimiter" arent working properly (I think they are returning null fields). If I manually enter some values this code works ex) linefromfile = line.strip('\n').split('\t').

The traceback error looks like this:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Hezekiah/PycharmProjects/Great Courses Python/testing.py", 
           line 14, in 
    if int(tuple1[1][:4]) == qdate:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: What are you actually typing in for these strings?  If you're typing `\t` for the delimiter, that's just a backslash followed by a 't' - the interpretation of that as an escape sequence for the tab character is something that applies to *string literals*, not strings from arbitrary other sources.

Comment: I am typing \n for stripped_character and \t for delimiter. Can you think of a way to turn this into a string literal?

Comment: Try `input("...").encode().decode("unicode-escape")` to apply the same escape handling.

Comment: My question has now been fully resolved. If #jasonharper leaves his comments as an answer I will mark it as correct.